# How to give option for enable GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, android-location

I want to show dialog box for turn on GPS when GPS is disable .

[image]

See the image. When i click on YES then should be automatically turn on my GPS without going into setting.

So , how can i enable GPS by select YES option ?

Comment: You can't if user manually turned their GPS off.

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit Since Android 6.0, it can.

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit we can. This OLA application is doing. Installed it and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of Google play service api since 7.0 called `SettingsApi`.

Location settings - While the `FusedLocationProviderApi` combines multiple sensors to give you the optimal location, the accuracy of the location your app receives still depends greatly on the settings enabled on the device (GPS, wifi, airplane mode, and others). Using the new [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) class, you can bring up a Location Settings dialog which displays a one-touch control for users to change their settings without leaving your app.

To use this API, first create a GoogleApiClient which supports at least `LocationServices.API`. Then connect the client to Google Play services:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
     .addApi(LocationServices.API)
     .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
     .build()
 ...
 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Then create a `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` and add all of the LocationRequests that the app will be using:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestHighAccuracy)
     .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);
```

For next steps please check here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

IMPORTANT: If the status code is RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, the client can call startResolutionForResult(Activity, int) to `bring up a dialog, asking for user's permission to modify the location settings to satisfy those requests.` The result of the dialog will be returned via onActivityResult(int, int, Intent). If the client is interested in which location providers are available, it can retrieve a LocationSettingsStates from the Intent by calling fromIntent(Intent)

Also please refer to this official repo: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos
if you want to grant the permission on API 23(Android M) at the running time.

Comment: Yes, this help me a lot. !

Comment: for some chinese phones like tecno this does not work